# How do you display a Wordpress post tag

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have the following post tag in my template
[image]

Basically I would like the tag "mytag" to display on my post page. So far I have:

```
<?php the_tag()?>
```

I'm pretty sure the syntax is wrong.

Comment: I have to enter at least 15 characters otherwise I would have just said `s`  :)

Comment: @ WheatBeak Thanks! That worked. Is there a way to output it just as text and not a link?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: For the very basics please read the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_tags();` with an `s` is the correct function.

This will output the text: `Tags: mytag`

If you just want `mytag` you'll have to add an empty string as an argument to replace the default `$before`

```
the_tags('');
```

**EDIT**

without links:

```
$mytags = get_the_tags();
if($mytags){
  foreach($mytags as $mytag) {
    echo $mytag->name; 
  }
}
```